# How to generate Entity-context only for one schema when multiple schema available in one database in Postgres sql with .Net Core?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the `Postgres` database for my project and have created 3 schemas named `mydb_dev`, `mydb_stage`, and `mydb_prod` in database 'temp_db'.
I am creating `.Net core` web application with the database first approach with entity framework.
Now, whenever I am trying to generate an entity model from the database it generates for all 3 databases. And I want to generate only one database that is `mydb_dev`.

I am using the following command to generate through the console.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=localhost;Database=temp_db;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models
```

Is there any way to generate an entity model only for one schema?

[image: Db snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

`Scaffold-DbContext` has a `-Schemas <String[]>` parameter.

> The schemas of tables to generate entity types for. If this parameter
> is omitted, all schemas are included.

So your command should look like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=localhost;Database=temp_db;Username=myuser;Password=mypassword" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models -Schemas "mydb_dev"
```

Comment: Hi, in this case you should accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers